# How to make required fields using JS

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint Form. How can I make a required field( people picker and date) using Java Scripts ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check the OOTB options first.  Obviously a list field marked required will not submit until it's filled in.

You can also setup validation in list setting under validation settings.  Enter a formula that can evaluate to TRUE to pass validation (Title = "TitleXYZ").  Custom error text can also be added.

There are endless options using JavaScript.  The basic SharePoint forms model (assuming your validating on the submit event) uses the PreSaveItem function:

```
  function PreSaveItem()
    {   
      if ("function"==typeof(PreSaveAction))
        {
          return PreSaveAction();
        }
   return true;
}
```

PreSaveAction function also allows override behavior for the Save button.  For example:

```
function PreSaveAction() {   
   return ifValidSSN();
}
```

You can find a good example of using this function
 [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx)

If you want more of a framework there are multiple jQuery validation plugins you can try.  I recommend [the jquery Validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org)

If you want some examples of using this plugin let me know